# Метод System.exit(0)

Tags: android, activity

Я поместила вызов метода `System.exit(0)` в `onBackPressed`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

и после нажатия на клавишу BACK (из первого активити), судя по логам, вызываются следующие методы обратного вызова:

```
onCreate
onStart
onResume
onBackPressed
```

После этого я запускаю приложение снова (неважно как - вызовом из списка запущенных приложением, или тапом по иконке приложения на домашнем экране), и вижу, что следующим вызывается метод `OnCreate`, минуя методы `onStop` и `onDestroy`. Каким образом завершается активность без вызова методов `onStop` и `onDestroy`? Убивается процесс, в котором запущено приложение?

Comment: Обычно System.exit как раз и предназначен для немедленного завершения.

Comment: Да, завершается сам процесс приложения. И к жизненному циклу это не имеет отношения.

Comment: минусовать то зачем?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вызов `System.exit(0)` перезапускает приложение, выкидывая последнюю activity.

Например, если из ActivityA открыта ActivityB, в которой делается вызов `System.exit(0)`, то приложение будет убито и сразу же перезапущено с ActivityA.

Источник: [Difference between finish() and System.exit(0)](//stackoverflow.com/a/30217826/4928642)

Comment: А что System.exit(0) не просто завершает приложение, а перезапускает его, за исключением последней активити? Почему тогда метод называется exit?..)

Comment: @Ksenia, потому что это аварийное завершение? А андроид перезапускает упавшие приложения? Понятия не имею. Просто решил погуглить. Что мешает проверить?

Comment: проверила, похоже на правду. Если из второго активити вызывать System.exit(0) , приложение перезапускатся, только уже с первой активити. А если из первого активити вызывать System.exit(0), то приложение закрывается, но тем не менее остаётся в списке запущенных приложений...

Comment: @Ksenia, так что тебе мешает вызвать `finish()`?

Comment: мне не нужно вызывать метод finish, я просто хотела понять, как работает метод System.exit(0) )